# How does float operations works in c? Big numbers weird results

Tags: c, floating-point

The following code gives some odd results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main()
{
    float t = 1.0;  
    float res;
    float myFltMax = 340282346638528859.0;
    printf("FLT_MAX %f\n", FLT_MAX);

    res = FLT_MAX - t;
    printf("res %f\n", res);

    res = myFltMax - t;
    printf("res myFltMax %f\n", res);

    return 1;

}
```

The results are:

```
FLT_MAX 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
res 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
res myFltMax 340282356122255360.000000
```

So, if i subtract 1 from FLT_MAX the result is the same and if i subtract 1 from other big float, the result is greater than initial number.

I am using gcc version 4.7.2.
Thank you.

Comment: ... and cue [this fantastic document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)! :)

Comment: Actually, if you want to get more or less exact result, you should avoid such operations. The best result you will get if numbers have the same power of 10.

Comment: float (as well as double or any other floating point formats) doesn't have infinite precision

Answer (score 3):

If you subtract 1 from `myFltMax` you don't get the difference greater than the initial number. You get the same number. Print `myFltMax` as well and you'll see that it's `340282356122255360` and not `340282346638528859`.

[Proof](http://ideone.com/zzfGRz).

Basically, the compiler rounds your `340282346638528859` to the nearest value that can be represented in the floating point type and that happens to be `340282356122255360`.

Comment: It is true, is the same result, but why is not less? What should i subtract from that value to get a different result?

Comment: In the comments you've been given a link to a wonderful paper. Study that and the floating point formats.